# Here i have written a C++ code which uses 2-dimension array and meant to perform rowsum but it is not giving proper output

Tags: c++

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int const rows=3;    //rows are kept constant
int const cols=3;    //columns are kept constant

void display(int arr[][cols],int rows,int cols);    //function prototype
int rowsum(int arr[][cols],int rows,int cols);    //function prototype


int main()
{

    int z [rows][cols];    //2-D array declaration
    int r,c;

        for(r=0;r<rows;r++)
        {
            for(c=0;c<cols;c++)
            {
             cout<<"Enter elements of array["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"]:";
             cin>>z[r][c];
            }
        }
          display(z,rows,cols);    //Function call
          rowsum(z,rows,cols);    //Function call

        return 0;

}
void display(int arr[][cols],int rows,int cols)    //function to display input
{
    int r,c;
    for(r=0;r<rows;r++)
    {
     for(c=0;c<cols;c++)
      {
       cout<<"Elements of array["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"]="<<arr[r][c]<<endl;

      }
    }

}
int rowsum(int arr[][cols],int rows,int cols)    //Function to perform rowsum
{
    int c,sum=0,r=0;
    for(c=0;c<cols;c++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[r][c];
        cout<<"the sum of rows is:"<<sum<<endl;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Above is a C++ code which is using 2-D array.It takes input from user and that input is displayed using a display function.After taking input i want to sum the rows ,for which i have written a function named rowsum but it not working properly .It does not gives desired output.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: You say it does not give the desired output. Please post an example of the desired output vs. the actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you have used a single loop instead of the required two for loops here. Hence what your code does is simply calculate the sum of 0th row (since `r=0`).

What you actually need to do is calculate the sum of one row (i.e. `for(c=0;c<cols;c++)`), `row` number of times. HTH!!

```
for(r=0;r<rows;r++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for(c=0;c<cols;c++) //calculates sum of rth row
    {
        sum += arr[r][c];
    }
    cout<<"Sum of row " << i <<" is " << sum ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you print out partial sums of the first row.

You should have two loops, one for row and one for columns and only print out the result once you've looped through all the columns.

Or if you only want the sum for a set row, at least move the print statement out of the loop so that you only get the final sum, not the intermediate results.